# Assert `is` in python unittest

Tags: python, unit-testing, python-unittest

What is the best way to do `assertEqual` with `unittest` in Python, but instead of testing `==` it tests `is`? I want to ensure I have the same object, not just objects that compare equal. This is important, because some of the objects I'm working with are heap types with wacky compare operators.

Answer (score 5):

That would be the [`assertIs`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.html#unittest.TestCase.assertIs) method.

Comment: I hate myself right now

Comment: @RenéG it's okay, we all have those moments.

Answer (score 4):

Use `assertIs` which does exactly what you want.

https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.html#unittest.TestCase.assertIs